# Connecting Asp.net c# to mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, connection-string

Hi i am having trouble Conneting my website to a mysql database.  My connection string is

```
"Server=MYSQL5005.Smarterasp.net;Database=db_9ad83a_mydb;Uid=9ad83a_mydb;Pwd=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;"
```

Previously, I was able using `AdoHelper.cs` class.

I would be happy if there is some kind of class-helper, but I would be satisfied if only code behind was provided. (Please note i want to do the following actions: `insert`, `update`, `select`, and `delete`) using C#.

Comment: What "trouble" are you having?  In what way is this failing?  Currently it sounds like you're asking us to just write your code for you, which is unlikely to happen.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: I don't see any syntax error in your connection string. Please double check the value for Server, Database, Uid and Pwd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Check your userid and password in database..And put correct credentials like this

```
connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=DB name;User Id=MyUser; password=your Password;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missed to provide reference to to MySql.

Right Click on Your Solution Name in Solution Explorer ---> Add Reference --- > Extions --- > Click on MySql

If this does not solve the problem, then check that the MySql server is working properly and accepting connections.